# How to produce all the combinations of the elements of two or more tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to compute all the combinations of two or more tensors. For example, for two tensors containing resp. the values `[1, 2]` and `[3, 4, 5]`, I would like to get the `6x2` tensor

```
[[1, 3],
 [1, 4],
 [1, 5],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 4],
 [2, 5]]
```

To do this, I came up with the following hack

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def combine(x, y):
  x, y = x[:, None], y[:, None]
  x1 = tf.concat([x, tf.ones_like(x)], axis=-1)
  y1 = tf.concat([tf.ones_like(y), y], axis=-1)
  return tf.reshape(x1[:, None] * y1[None], (-1, 2))

x = tf.constant([1, 2])
y = tf.constant([3, 4, 5])
print(combine(x, y))
# tf.Tensor(
# [[1 3]
#  [1 4]
#  [1 5]
#  [2 3]
#  [2 4]
#  [2 5]], shape=(6, 2), dtype=int32)
```

However I am not satisfied with this solution:

- It uses multiplication to combine the elements, which is clearly overkilled
- It does not easily generalize to an arbitrary combination of *n* tensors

Is there a more efficient and/or general way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily with [`tf.meshgrid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/meshgrid):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def combine(x, y):
  xx, yy = tf.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
  return tf.stack([tf.reshape(xx, [-1]), tf.reshape(yy, [-1])], axis=1)

x = tf.constant([1, 2])
y = tf.constant([3, 4, 5])
print(combine(x, y).numpy())
# [[1 3]
#  [1 4]
#  [1 5]
#  [2 3]
#  [2 4]
#  [2 5]]
```

Comment: And its easy to generalize to multiple vectors: `tf.stack([tf.reshape(e, (-1,))[:, None] for e in tf.meshgrid(*args, indexing='ij')], axis=-1)`. Thanks!

Comment: @user209974 Yes, either that or `tf.reshape(tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(*args, indexing='ij'), axis=-1), (-1, len(args)))` works.

Comment: Actually this last one does not work, maybe you meant something like: `tf.transpose(tf.reshape(tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(*args, indexing='ij')), (len(args), -1)))`

Comment: @user209974 Yours also works, but I tested mine with `args = list(map(tf.constant, ([2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]))); m = tf.reshape(tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(*args, indexing='ij'), axis=-1), (-1, len(args))); print(m.numpy())` and the result seems right...